# How to create DMG file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

How to create application file (.DMG) of my xcode code so that I can distribute it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Your question is better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check also DropDMG:
http://c-command.com/dropdmg/

Used by quite some developers, makes life much easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Disk Utility - File - New - Disk Image From Folder - Select your Folder...